# Should I use "will have" here or "would have"?

Tags: grammar

In response to "Michael said in a meeting last week that this is an easy task", my gut feeling is to respond like this:

> "That sounds like something Michael **would have** said. But I don't agree with that"

But looking at [this](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/will-have-and-would-have), this is "looking back from the present", so it should be:

> "That sounds like something Michael **will have** said. But I don't agree with that".

The latter sounds weird and unidiomatic to my ears. I find that I often use "would have" to imply uncertainty even when looking back from the present like this example. Am I wrong?

Comment: Use of _will have_ always implies a time line of several events, with befores and afters being important. Since there's only one event and you weren't there to witness it, _would_ is really your only option here.

Comment: "That sounds like something Michael would say" is also a possibility.

Comment: I can see "That sounds like something Michael will have said" used as a variant of "That sounds like something Michael has said", modally showing more confidence in the supposition that he has. Using 'would' may mean that you know he hasn't, **or** that you're not at all sure he has done.

Answer (score 0):

Both you and the page you link to are correct. The confusion is that you're talking about a conditional. This might not be clear because the first sentence of your quote leaves that condition unsaid but implied by the context (which is perfectly fine and idiomatically correct).

If we include what unsaid part might be:

> "That sounds like something Michael would have said **if he had been there**. But I don't agree with that."

We see that it is obviously bound by the rules for conditionals and uses *would have* instead of *will have*.

Comment: I'm not sure if I used a good example. What about this? "The batch sent five minutes ago would have included everything you need". Is this correct? Or does it have to be "will have included"?

Comment: "if had he been there" is not said; it's simply "had he been there". ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=if+had+he+been+there%2Chad+he+been+there&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chad%20he%20been%20there%3B%2Cc0))

Comment: @LPH I included the "if" as it's not especially unnatural, but makes the conditional nature of the sentence unambiguous.

Comment: @lfk - That depends on whether there is a condition unsaid about the batch. If it actually includes the "everything you need" then _will_. If it doesn't (or possibly doesn't) because of some condition, then _would_.

Comment: @LPH - I had messed up the word order as I originally wrote it to exclude the "if", I transposed the "he" and "had" to correct for that.

Comment: The OP states that Michael _did_ speak at the meeting, so I interpreted 'something he would have said' as meaning 'a typical comment of his'.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins am I then correct in assuming that "would" implies more uncertainty? Even if I can't think of a specific condition, but I just feel like something could've gone wrong and I'm not fully confident the batch included everything.